# CDN links not working

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, cdn

I am reading on Google that CDN links are better to use because of speed and an extra layer of security. I am new to WordPress Dev. I placed the CDN links in a JS file and enqueued. However, it's not taking effect on my site.

**custom-js.js**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php

function load_css_js() {
    wp_register_style( 'child-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', false, NULL, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-css' );

    wp_register_script( 'child-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-js.js', array( 'jquery' ), NULL, false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'child-js' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_css_js' );

?>
```

Comment: so what shows up in your generated html?

Comment: @MarcB Just HTML, no fancy Bootstrap elements. No color, no neat buttons, etc...pretty plain

Comment: did you add those links in a js file? they belong into your html

Comment: Please attach the generated HTML and your JS file in an SSCC example. See http://sscce.org/ and https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: "and an extra layer of security" --- how so? It's actually the opposite.

Comment: @zerkms not sure...I'm new to all this and I just read it [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/wordpress-cdn-content-delivery-network-configuration.html)

Comment: @ggkid2002 it's a BS there )

Comment: @zerkms ugh....so all this isn't a recommended practice then?

Comment: @ggkid2002 I'm only speaking about it being "more secure"

Comment: you can try to use [jare.io](http://www.jare.io), a free and instant CDN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Before anything else. Are you attempting to build a Child theme on top of a Parent theme that **does not all ready use Bootstrap**?

2) Have your set up your Child themes style.css (see Child Themes link below)?

**Loading Scripts/Stylesheets:**

You should have something similar to these functions inside your `functions.php` file.

Generally speaking you shouldn't need to load jQuery though, it's all ready there by [default](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress) (**see Codex: Default Scripts Included and Registered by WordPress**) so check a page with DEV Tools to see if it's loading (unless you want to use another CDNs Library, then you need to disable the default one so you don't have jQuery loading twice.

[Codex: Function Reference/wp enqueue script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

[Codex: Child Themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes)

[Codex: Function Reference/wp enqueue style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

Enqueue JS

```
function my_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js', '2.1.3', true ); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.5', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts');
```

Enqueue CSS

```
function my_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', '//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles');
```

Comment: Shouldnt the Enqueue CSS code be using `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead? Your example has me using the parent theme's stylesheet, no? Otherwise, how will the code I put into my child theme's style.css take effect?

Comment: ggkid2002 - you're right. Use get_stylesheet_directory_uri() for your child theme (and even get_stylesheet_uri() for your child theme style.css). Also, no need to separate this into two functions AND do not include jquery as a dependency of itself (see the answer's jquery enqueue).

Comment: @Joe-NewNine I understood everything except the dependency part. What about his code signaled to you that he was using jquery as a dependency of itself?

Comment: wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js', array('jquery') '2.1.3', true ); <--- the "array( 'jquery' )" (now removed) means this script needs jquery to load before this one does.

Comment: No, that was changed. Did you check to see if it was loaded by default though?

Comment: @vanburenx yes I removed the jquery enqueue script line and everything seemed fine...not sure if this means it was already using jquery (still a newbie here) but if nothing broke I'm assuming it worked

Comment: I here ya, we all started somewhere and sorry for the confusion! Good luck!